# SQL Statement in VBA can not recognize my excel worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, import-from-excel, data-import

> Error: Invalid Object Name 'Tabelle1$'

I am trying to reference to Tabelle1 as a worksheet.
As I am new to vba I don't understand why the script can't recognize it, or what I have to do so that it does.

Thanks for any help.

```
Sub WriteDataIntoSQLTable()

Dim cn                    As Object
Dim strQuery              As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strQuery = "[dbo].[MyTable]"

 With cn
     .Provider = "sqloledb"
     .ConnectionString = "Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
     .Open
End With


  
s = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;Driver=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes].strQuery( ldf_nr,datum, abteilung_na, positions_nr, positions_na, ma_nr, ma_na, ma_plan_beginn, ma_plan_ende, ma_plan_pause, ma_plan_dauer_netto  ) " _
& "SELECT  a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3, a.Col4, a.Col5, a.Col6, a.Col7, a.Col8, a.Col9, a.Col10, a.Col11 " _
& "FROM [Tabelle1$] as a" _
& "LEFT JOIN [ODBC;Driver=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes].strQuery as b ON a.Col1 = b.[ldf_nr]" _
& "WHERE b.[ldf_nr] Is Null"
cn.Execute s
cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If your table name is `Tabelle1`, why do you then write `Tabelle1$`?

Comment: I am sorry, the worksheet name is Tabelle1$, not Tabelle1.

Comment: I believe the "$" is an invalid character, so please remove it (it seems to be in my language at least)

Comment: I changed it, but unfortunately it didn't work out for me..

Comment: Did you still get "Invalid Object Name ..." with the new name

Answer (score 0):

there is what is working for me :

```
With Worksheets("Tabelle1").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=*SERVER ADRESS*;UID=*ID*;PWD=*PASSWORD*;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=*PC NAME*;DATABASE=*DATABASENAME*", Destination:=Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array("*SQL String Query*")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Tabelle1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

You need to replace things between "*" by your data to make it work.